# What is the difference between "structured" and "structural" feedback?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, adjectives, present-perfect

I wrote something about a team providing "structural feedback" and a native English speaker corrected it to "structured feedback".

When I googled for the difference, I couldn't come up with much.

Are there any native speakers here who have a feel for the difference between "structured" and "structural" feedback, what different meanings they might express, and/or why one or the other might be preferred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Structured feedback* refers to the shape of the feedback. It is feedback which is presented in a structured manner.

*Structural feedback* refers to the content of the feedback. It is feedback on structural aspects of writing/art/etc.

*Structured feedback* is a common collocation. *Structural feedback* is not as much of a well-used term, but its meaning is clear.

Comment: Structured feedback example: organizing my comments to you into categories like Plusses and Minuses.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you?